C# Как не писать вирус если ты его не пишешь?)
написал прогу которая через реестр включает диспетчер задач смену пароля, снимает ограничения с дисков(чтоб они отображались в проводнике) и т.д
и через время примерно от нескольких часов до нескольких суток (удивительно что не сразу) антивирусник винды говорит что моя прога вирус и удаляет ее и не дает скачать, есть какоето решение?

Есть - купить сертификат для своего софта и подписать им. А так, ну, отправлять антивирусникам репорт о том, что программа не вирус, соберете толпу, мб перепроверят получше и выяснят что не так.

Вариант получше - удалить антивирус Windows. Оно скорее удалит вашу систему, чем настоящие вирусы.

@EvgeniyZ покупать сертификат ради 10 строк кода, ну такое)

Вы это говорите антивирусам, не мне. Я вам лишь даю варианты, которые намекают на то, что с этим стоит просто смириться. Уверены, что там безопасный код, все, спите спокойно, а других людей можете убедить, например, Open Source проектом. Не хотите, ну чтож, со временем, если много скачиваний будет вашего софта, репутация может покрыть ложные срабатывания. Правда ложные-ли они, вопрос..., ибо вы лезете в то, во что лезть особ не желательно, а значит ваш софт может быть вредным (не думаю, что вы знаете OS лучшее ее разработчиков) и детект не просто так его пометил. Короче, просто смиритесь)
